# Passsing View to PageFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm able to pass string value to PageFragment via Bundle/Instance. But How can I pass a view  ?

I tried to create a public LinearLayout in PageFragment then used `PageFragment.linearlayout.addView(myview);` in FragmentPagerAdapter. But it didnt worked

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {  
    public static LinearLayout linearlayout; 

     public static PageFragment newInstance(String title) {

         PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         bundle.putString("title", title);
         pageFragment.setArguments(bundle);
         return pageFragment;
     }



     @Override  
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
     }  

     @Override  
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_quiz, container, false);  
         tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.questionText);  
         tv.setText(getArguments().getString("title"));         
         linearlayout= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.questionList);

         return view;  
     }
}
```

FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter { 
...
@Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int index) { 
    PageFragment.linearlayout.addView(myview); //=> doesnt work
        String mytext = "My Text";          
             return PageFragment.newInstance(index + mytext);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've tried is not a correct way to do what you want. First of all, in the `getItem()` method of the adapter the `Fragment`'s view isn't yet built so the `LinearLayout` will be null. If you need to add a View to the fragment's view at that level then you should add it directly in the `onCreateView()` callback of the `Fragment`(passing to the fragment only the data needed to populate that view). Otherwise create a method to access the parent `LinearLayout` and add the View **after** the fragments are fully built. Keep in mind that you need to take care of that added view to show it again as the fragments may be destroyed by your adapter.

Another approach would be to have that extra view in the fragment's layout from the start(visibility `GONE`) and only toggle its visibility when needed.

Don't make views(like your `LinearLayout`) static in classes as you may create memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it really helped. I will try to creating method and adding the View after the fragments are fully built. But in which class/method fragments are fully built ? It is not built yet in `getItem` ; so where can I add `View` ?

Comment: @metemet06 You could do it by posting a `Runnable` from the `onCreate` or `onResume` method. But once again, if you're planing to add the view to every fragment from the adapter and at the start considering doing it in the fragment itself.

Comment: Yes, I'll add view to every fragment from adapter. Sorry maybe its a simple question but Will `Runnable` be in  **PageFragment's onCreate**  and if it's possible; can you give me a sample how to use :  `myview.post(new Runnable() {public void run() {  ... } })`  Thanks

Comment: I think I achieve it but as you said :  **fragments may be destroyed by your adapter** . fragments are destroyed.  I just want to get viewpager fragment position; And then getting this position's content from database and set it to textview/linearlayout in fragmnet. So every time when page changed, content will be changed.

Comment: @metemet06 Using an adapter means that by default you'll be able to get a reference to maximum 3 fragments(the current one and one on each side if possible). I was referring to something like this `view.post(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + r.id.theIdOfTheViewPager + ":" + viewPager.getCurentItem()) //..update}});`. The other fragments will need to be updated on demand as the user swipes left/right.